# Convert Map(key-value) into spark scala Data-frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

convert myMap =  Map([Col_1->1],[Col_2->2],[Col_3->3])
    to Spark scala Data-frame key as column and value as column value,i am not 
   getting expected result, please check my code and provide solution.

```
 var finalBufferList = new ListBuffer[String]()
 var finalDfColumnList = new ListBuffer[String]()
 var myMap:Map[String,String] = Map.empty[String,String]
 for ((k,v) <- myMap){
      println(k+"->"+v)
      finalBufferList += v 
      //finalDfColumnList += "\""+k+"\""
      finalDfColumnList += k

    }
    val dff = Seq(finalBufferList.toSeq).toDF(finalDfColumnList.toList.toString())
    dff.show()

My result : 

+------------------------+
|List(Test, Rest, Incedo)|
+------------------------+
|               [4, 5, 3]|
+------------------------+

Expected result :
+------+-------+-------+
|Col_1 | Col_2 | Col_3 |
+------+-------+-------+
| 4    |  5    |  3    |
+------+-------+-------+
please give me suggestion .
```

Comment: if you have solution then please suggest me.

Comment: in scala language

Comment: val values = Map([Col_1->1],[Col_2->2],[Col_3->3],[Col_4->4]).map((x,y) =>x, y))
import spark.implicits._
val df = values.toDF

Comment: Hi  Ramesh ,Please check it and suggest me please

Comment: I have answered below with a caution @Ved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have defined your `Map` as

```
val myMap = Map("Col_1"->"1", "Col_2"->"2", "Col_3"->"3")
```

then you should create `RDD[Row]` *using the values* as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(Row.fromSeq(myMap.values.toSeq)))
```

then you create a `schema` *using the keys* as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val schema = StructType(myMap.keys.toSeq.map(StructField(_, StringType)))
```

then finally use `createDataFrame` function to create the `dataframe` as

```
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
df.show(false)
```

finally you should have

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|Col_1|Col_2|Col_3|
+-----+-----+-----+
|1    |2    |3    |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

**But remember all this would be useless if you are working in small dataset.**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One question, can you please explain little bit on your last point where you said "all this would be useless if you are working in small dataset." ?